# Regex DD-MM working in JavaScript, but not in HTML pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, html

I have written regex to check valid DD-MM.
Regex :

> ^((0[1-9]|[12]\d|(3[01]))+-(0[13578]|1[02]))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|(3[0]))+-(0[469]|1[1]))|((0[1-9]|[1]\d|(2[0-9]))+-(0[2]))$

It works fine in Javascript / TypeScript.

```
public isValidDob(ddmm) : boolean {
    const regex = /^((0[1-9]|[12]\d|(3[01]))+\-(0[13578]|1[02]))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|(3[0]))+\-(0[469]|1[1]))|((0[1-9]|[1]\d|(2[0-9]))+\-(0[2]))$/gm;
    const re = new RegExp( regex, "g" );
    const isValid = re.test(ddmm);
    return isValid;
  }
```

But in Angular HTML NgForm, pattern regex its not working.

```
<input type="text" 
[(ngModel)]="person.wishDob" name="wishDob" #wishDob="ngModel" 
pattern="^((0[1-9]|[12]\d|(3[01]))+\-(0[13578]|1[02]))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|(3[0]))+\-(0[469]|1[1]))|((0[1-9]|[1]\d|(2[0-9]))+\-(0[2]))$" 
minlength="5" maxlength="5" />
```

Am i missing character escaping here? OR () AND OR | is not allowed in HTML pattern?

Comment: Try removing the backslashes before hyphens.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have tried removing \ , but still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After modifying the HTML part of regex, I am able to fix it.
Please find modified part. Suggest if you want to add anything.

> pattern="^((0[1-9]|(1[0-9])|(2[0-9])|(3[01]))+-(0[13578]|1[02]))|((0[1-9]|(1[0-9])|(2[0-9])|(3[0]))+-(0[469]|1[1]))|((0[1-9]|(1[0-9])|(2[0-9]))+-(0[2]))$"